# View table structure in YQL

Tags: yql

I'm a bit new to YQL, but I was wondering if there is a way to just see the data in the tables without specifying a key?  For example, how can I determine what a particular player's key is from the tables themselves?

For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fantasysports.players WHERE player_name = 'Tom Brady'
```

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to query with YQL to see actual sports statistics, only for fantasy leagues.